# Changing the order of middle levels of a tensor (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Imagine I have the following numpy array:

```
array([[['Xa0', 'Ya0'],
        ['Xa1', 'Ya1'],
        ['Xa2', 'Ya2']],

       [['Xb0', 'Yb0'],
        ['Xb1', 'Yb1'],
        ['Xb2', 'Yb2']],

       [['Xc0', 'Yc0'],
        ['Xc1', 'Yc1'],
        ['Xc2', 'Yc2']]], dtype='<U3')
```

How could I change the ordering to have the following:

```
array([[['Xa2', 'Ya2'],
        ['Xa1', 'Ya1'],
        ['Xa0', 'Ya0']],

       [['Xb2', 'Yb2'],
        ['Xb1', 'Yb1'],
        ['Xb0', 'Yb0']],

       [['Xc2', 'Yc2'],
        ['Xc1', 'Yc1'],
        ['Xc0', 'Yc0']]], dtype='<U3')
```

?

P.S.: The entries are floats, not strings...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've just found the answer.

By using numpy.flip(tensor, axis=1)

Comment: It looks like numpy has a lot of methods that are redundant like this. I mean, noone uses them frequently. You could do the same thing using reverse slicing by `axis=1`: `tensor[:, ::-1, :]`